# javascript to create table php mysql to save data

Tags: javascript, php

I need a table where the user enters how many rows and columns needed, they enter the numbers and the next page creates the table.

They will enter the info which will be saved into a database. The only way I can think to do this is with dynamic tables, is there a better way? Here is some super basic code, I haven't worked out the full table, wanted to get feedback before I continue in case there is a better way and I need to change course.

Simple form:

```
  How many rows <input type="number" id="rowNumber"/><br>
  How many columns <input type="number" id="colNumber"/><br>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Checkout</button>

     function myFunction() {
       var rowNumber = document.getElementById('rowNumber').value;
       var colNumber = document.getElementById('colNumber').value;

       window.location.href = "website/test.php?rowNumber="+rowNumber+"&colNumber="+colNumber;
}
```

**test.php**

```
  <?php
    $rowNumber=$_GET['rowNumber'];
    $colNumber=$_GET['colNumber'];
  ?>

<script>
var numRows = "<? echo $rowNumber ?>";
var numCols = "<? echo $colNumber ?>";

var tableString = "<table>",
    body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
    div = document.createElement('div');

for (row = 1; row < numRows; row += 1) {

    tableString += "<tr onclick=\"fnselect(this)\"<? if($rowID == "A") { echo "class ='selected'";} ?>>";

    for (col = 1; col < numCols; col += 1) {

        tableString += "<td>" + "R" + row + "C" + col + "" + "<input type='text' />" + "</td>";
    }
    tableString += "</tr>";
}

tableString += "</table>";
div.innerHTML = tableString;
body.appendChild(div);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into jQuery DataTables.  A lot of nice functionality in there.

You can either bind to a JSON data source, or create your own rows manually like this URL: 
  https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

So, to use this, you have to reference jquery AND the data tables script.  You'll have to either reference them from their given URLs, or download the scripts (I recommend the latter otherwise you create references to outside servers).